# Entity Framework - multiple invalid column name for the same property

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have my page loading data correctly but when I add:

```
.Include(x => x.User);
```

I get:

```
Invalid column name 'User_UserId'.
Invalid column name 'User_UserId'.
Invalid column name 'User_UserId'.
Invalid column name 'User_UserId'.



public partial class User
{
        public Guid UserId { get; set; } //Primary key
        public virtual ICollection<UserOpenId> UserOpenIds { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserRecipeNote> UserRecipeNotes { get; set; }        
        public virtual ICollection<UsersInRole> UsersInRole { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserFilter> Preferences { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserOpenId
{
        public int Id { get; set; } //Primary key
        public Guid UserId { get; set; } //Foreign key
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The other User properties are the same as UserOpenId with an Id as primary key and UserId as foreign key.

When I do add-migration the SQL relationships all look correct:

```
CreateTable(
                "dbo.User",
                c => new
                    {
                        UserId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                        //other properties
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserId);

CreateTable(
                "dbo.UserOpenId",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        UserId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                        //other properties
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.User", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId);
```

I have configured the relationships like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
  .HasMany(e => e.UserOpenIds)
  .WithRequired(e => e.User)
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I think the yellow screen of death is to do with the relationships, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you try to add `.HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)` after `.WithRequired(e => e.User)`? I'd be surprised if it fixes the problem because the migration looks like EF has infered the correct FK property. But it least it completes the Fluent mapping ... and who knows...

Comment: That made no difference. It pointed me in the right direction though! I got a compilation error trying to add that line to the Blog property. My page loads when I comment out the Blog property, it is a 0..1 relationship to a User so I shall look into that, thanks!